# Calculation with parseFloat looses decimal places

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, parsefloat

I need to calculate a few numbers. It works ok so far, BUT it looses the original decimal places (here: 50 cent). Any idea why this is happening?

```js
$("select").on("change", function () {
  var sum1 = parseFloat($(this).val()) * parseFloat($(this).data("price"));
  var sum2 = parseFloat($("#orgPrice").data("price"));
  var sum3 = parseFloat(sum1) + parseFloat(sum2);
  $("#total").text(sum3.toFixed(2));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div id="orgPrice" data-price="100,00"></div>

<select id="subcode_060" class="custom-select custom-select-sm" data-description="UPGRADES" data-subdescription="X to Y" data-price="3560,50">
  <option value="0" selected>0</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
  <option value="5">5</option>
</select>

<div id="total">0.00</div>
```

Comment: Use dot `.` instead of  comma `,` `3560.50`

Comment: Yes, that hint helped me out, thank you!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use a `.` and not a `,` See the only change only happend here, from

```
data-price="3560,50"
```

to

```
data-price="3560.50"
```

```js
$("select").on("change", function () {

  var sum1 = parseFloat($(this).val()) * parseFloat($(this).data("price"));
  var sum2 = parseFloat($("#orgPrice").data("price"));
  var sum3 = parseFloat(sum1) + parseFloat(sum2);

  $("#total").text(sum3.toFixed(2));

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="orgPrice" data-price="100,00"></div>
 
 <select id="subcode_060" class="custom-select custom-select-sm" data-description="UPGRADES" data-subdescription="X to Y" data-price="3560.50">
   <option value="0" selected>0</option>
   <option value="1">1</option>
   <option value="2">2</option>
   <option value="3">3</option>
   <option value="4">4</option>
   <option value="5">5</option>
</select>

<div id="total">0.00</div>
```

**Note:** Of course you also want to change `data-price="100,00"` to `data-price="100.00"` it just doesn't really effect anything cause it's `.00`

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `.` instead of `,` for the decimal separator in `data-price`.

`data-price="3560.50"`

Here's the updated fiddle?: https://jsfiddle.net/ub4j7d7z/3/